# Joomla Proforms Basic Form sends no email

Tags: forms, joomla, smtp, php

We use 1&1-Server and installed Joomla. There we want to use forms. I have installed Proforms Basic Forms. I also wrote the email adresses to be sent. But we don't get any emails. I tried smtp und phpmail. Can anyone help?

Comment: And you are sure your SMTP info is correct?